# Why do git fetch origin and git fetch <remote> <srcBranch>:<destBranch> behave differently?

Tags: git, fetch

While I am working on `child-branch` on my working tree, I am informed that the remote `main` (master) branch was updated. Then, I want to merge those changes into my `child-branch`, without the need to checkout and pull `main`. If I use `git fetch --all`, I don't get the result I expect:

```
user MINGW64 /d/DATA/Sources/Git/GitTest (child-branch)
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 652 bytes | 54.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/myrepo/GitTest
   b84530e..4d6f085  main       -> origin/main

user MINGW64 /d/DATA/Sources/Git/GitTest (child-branch)
$ git merge main
Already up to date.
```

But, if I go with `git fetch origin main:main`, it does do what I expect:

```
user MINGW64 /d/DATA/Sources/Git/GitTest (child-branch)
$ git fetch origin main:main
From https://github.com/myrepo/GitTest
   b84530e..4d6f085  main       -> main

user MINGW64 /d/DATA/Sources/Git/GitTest (child-branch)
$ git merge main
Updating b84530e..4d6f085
Fast-forward
 File_02 | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 File_02
```

I want to understand why fetch behaves different with these different parameters because I am working on a project with many repositories, and normally I work on a child-branch of the master branch in each repository.

I want to write a command that updates the master branches of each repository contained in my project folder automatically, so that I don't need to checkout and pull each master branch of each repository, and later I can just merge those changes into my child branches. I tried this:

```
find . -name .git -type d | xargs -n1 -I% sh -c 'echo %; git --git-dir=% --work-tree=%/.. fetch --all --recurse-submodules;'
```

But it doesn't work because `fetch --all` does not do what I expect, and I cannot use `fetch origin main:main` because each repository may have different names for the master branches (the name of the master branch in the remote can be *master*, *integration* or *main*)

Is it possible to use some git command similar to `fetch --all` that allows me to have the changes ready to merge into my local child-branches?

Comment: "because fetch --all does not do what I expect" You keep saying that. You need to accept that that command does not mean what you think it means. It means: if this (one) repo has multiple remotes, fetch into remote tracking branches from all of those remotes.

Comment: "I want to understand why fetch behaves different with these different parameters" Because they have different parameters and mean totally different things!

Comment: "the name of the master branch in the remote can be master, integration or main" Then start by giving a command that finds out what it is. Even better, hook a local branch called `main` to the remote HEAD no matter what its name is! Local and remote branch names do not have to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The key to understanding this aspect of Git is that *your branches* are completely independent of *any other Git's branches*.  You may or may not choose to use similar *names*, e.g., if you have a branch named `feature/tall`, you might want some other Git also to have a branch named `feature/tall`.  But when you do this, these are still *completely different branches*.  You do not share *branches* with some other Git repository.  You only share *commits* with that Git repository.  They have *their own* branch names.

#### Long

The command:

```
git fetch --all
```

means: *run `git fetch` against all remotes*.  So the question here is how many remotes you have listed: what does `git remote` print?  If it prints one remote name, specifically `origin`, then `git fetch --all` means the same thing as `git fetch origin`.

What *that* means ... well, your job at this point is to read [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).  It is long and quite complicated and if you need help interpreting it, that would be unsurprising.  So let's press on:

> But, if I go with `git fetch origin main:main`, it does do what I expect ...

Let's take a look at the SYNOPSIS section of the documentation:

> **SYNOPSIS**
> `git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`
> `git fetch [<options>] <group>`
> `git fetch --multiple [<options>] [(<repository> | <group>)…​]`
> `git fetch --all [<options>]`

All the various options start with one or two dashes, so `origin` is not an option.  You are not using `--all` this time, so the final line is not relevant, and you are not using `--multiple`, so the third line is not relevant.  Hence `origin` can only either be a `<group>`—in which case no additional parameters are allowed; `main:main` would be an error here—or a `<repository>`.

This means the *first* line is the one that applies: we're doing `git fetch <repository> <refspec>`.  So `origin` here is the *repository* and `main:main` is the *refspec*.

The next sections of the documentation are quite long and confusing: `git fetch` has a very long history behind it, dating back to before the invention of the so-called *remote*.  We get to skip over most of this because `origin` *is* a `remote`, so we now can skip directly down to this section:

> **REMOTES**
> The name of one of the following can be used instead of a URL as `<repository>` argument:
>
> - a remote in the Git configuration file: `$GIT_DIR/config`,
> - [two more options snipped here].
>
> All of these also allow you to omit the refspec from the command line because they each contain a refspec which git will use by default.

Hence `origin` supplies both a URL—so that you don't have to put in some long `https://` or `ssh://` URL here—*and* a *default refspec*.  That default refspec is the one that `git fetch --all` uses; you'd get the same effect with `git fetch origin`, which omits the separate `<refspec>` argument.

Last, then, we need to look at what a `<refspec>` is.  This requires going back up from the **REMOTES** section, and it gets rather confusing and detailed.

Rather than quoting the documentation at this point, I will summarize this, leaving out the newfangled negative refspecs.  In its *second*-simplest form, a refspec is just a pair of words, separated by a colon, such as `main:main`.  The name on the left is the *source* and the name on the right is the *destination*.

The *default* refspec for most remotes, however, is *not* this second-simplest form.  In fact, the setting you are likely to find, if you run:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This uses *fully qualified* references, i.e., names that begin with `refs/`.  A fully qualified reference is unambiguous.

Given a reference like `zorg`, is this a *branch* name, or a *tag* name, or what?  It's not immediately clear to anyone or anything, including Git itself.  *Branch* names, in Git, internally begin with `refs/heads/`.  *Tag* names internally begin with `refs/tags/`.  Another form of name, the *remote-tracking name*, begins with `refs/remotes/` and goes on to name the specific remote.  Using this fully-spelled-out form tells Git that `refs/heads/zorg` is definitely a branch name, or `refs/remotes/origin/zorg` is definitely a remote-tracking name, while `refs/tags/v1.2` is definitely a tag name.  When writing any form of script, it's wise to use the fully-spelled-out names, so that there is no ambiguity.

When you use an ambiguous name, such as `main`, Git will try to *guess* whether this is a branch name, or a tag name, or whatever.  If there is in fact a branch named `main`, and no tag named `main`, Git will guess that you really meant `refs/heads/main`.  So:

```
git fetch origin main:main
```

winds up being short for:

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main
```

because there *is* a branch named `main` (and no tag named `main` to confuse things).

In the end, this explains why your `git fetch origin main:main` did what you wanted it to do: Git qualified `main` to `refs/heads/main` (in both cases) and wound up updating your local `refs/heads/main`.  But note that this is very different from the *default* refspec of:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This default refspec makes use of two special features:

- It begins with a plus sign `+`.  This makes it a *forced* refspec.  That is, the `:destination` part of the update will happen regardless of whether the update is a *fast-forward* operation.  For more about that, search StackOverflow.
- It uses an asterisk `*` in both the source and destination parts.  The source part, `refs/heads/*`, matches *every branch in the source repository*.  That is, we match all branch names over on `origin`.  The destination part, `refs/remotes/origin/*`, has its `*` expanded to put in whatever name was matched on the left side.  So *their*—`origin`'s—`main` branch becomes *our* `refs/remotes/origin/main`, i.e., our *remote-tracking name* for their `main`.  If they have a branch named `develop`, our Git will create or update a remote-tracking name `refs/remotes/origin/develop`.  If they have a branch named `feature/tall`, our Git will create or update our `refs/remotes/origin/feature/tall`.

In this way, running `git fetch origin` will have our Git get, from their Git repository over at `origin`, *all* new commits they have on *all* branches, bring them over, put them in our Git repository here, and create-or-update *all* our remote-tracking names to match their branch names.  That way, after `git fetch origin`, we have an `origin/*` for every *branch* they have over at `origin`.

> Is it possible to use some git command similar to `fetch --all` that allows me to have the changes ready to merge into my local child-branches?

That's just `git fetch`.  It will update all the `origin/*` names.  *These are the names you should use to refer to commits you got from the other Git.*

Your branches are not *child* branches.  Branches have no parent/child relationships.  Humans being human, we like to use same or similar *names* to keep track of similar commits, so after we make a branch `zorg` in *our* Git we often like to have some other Git call *its* branch `zorg`, or maybe `jean-baptiste/zorg` or something.  That lets us keep them together in our heads.  But that's just for *us*.  All *Git* cares about are the commit hash IDs.  Git has names—in our repository, for us to use, and in each other Git repository, for each other Git to use—to help *find* the hash IDs of commits.  But it's only the *commits themselves* that matter.  We can change our names any time we like.

Comment: Great thanks @torek for such a detailed explanation. I was mixing up the origin/master with the master in the remote repository. Now I guess what I have to do is use `fetch --all` and then use the command diff against origin/master, instead of master (since it is not fast-forwarded). I think it is clear now. Many, many thanks.

Comment: @AjStar08: If you're a beginner, never use `fetch --all`. If you're more advanced: use `--all` only when you were about to do `for remote in origin upstream; do git fetch $remote; done`. `--all` means *all remotes* and only makes sense if you have more than one remote.

Comment: Noted. I was using --all because I have one project with two remotes. It is a weird workaround setup for two different deployment environments. Thanks for the remark!